# SQL Select from a single compound table

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, max

I'm new to SQL, so apologies if I got the nomenclature all wrong (or if the solution is blindingly obvious).

My code is something like:

```
Select Client_id, Max(Year_end_date),  Acct_Nbr    
From  (   
      --  ** subquery ** 
) As AA    
Group By Client_id, Acct_nbr;
```

The columns in the subquery is the same as the main query. However I get some duplicates in the answer - meaning same for a given `Client_id` DB2 returns multiple rows with different dates - for example

```
Client_id | Year_end_date | Acct_nbr   
-------------------------------------
20001       2003-12-31      01    
20001       2005-12-31      01
```

Any idea why?

Comment: please post your subquery as well

Comment: You have a `group by`, so my best guess is that the values are actually different -- just hidden characters or unexpected confusion, such as zero and capital-O.

Comment: The subquery is kinda long and complex. What I was trying to get at was, if all the calculations are done in the subquery, and I can comment out the main query to see the subquery results - why would it matter what the subquery was? The main query should just return the max(Year_end_date), right?

Comment: @Ardia - you're correct.  I'm a little curious, though, because the listed top-level query isn't something that generally needs nesting.  If there's hidden characters (usually whitespace), you need to fix your data; doing `TRIM` in this statement to fix it up isn't a good long-term solution, because it makes it harder for the db to use an index.

Comment: Just wanted to add: Yes the problem was in Acct_nbr. I just didn't notice the (a few of the) values were different. Newbie mistake. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select '>>' || Client_id || '<<', Max(Year_end_date), '>>' || Acct_Nbr || '<<'
From  (   
      --  ** subquery ** 
) As AA    
Group By Client_id, Acct_nbr;
```

You can also try calling `TRIM()` on the Client_id and Acc_nbr fields in the sub-query.  I think you have some hidden spaces there.

Comment: ...although from the looks of it (and hopefully) `client_id` is an autogen, numeric id, so most likely culprit is `acct_nbr`.